# Kingston DT 101 G2 16gb Flash Drive not showing on desktop

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Somehow my flash drive is not showing on my desktop anymore. Maybe it wasn't disconnected properly. There is light on it so there is power but still not showing on my 2 x 3 GHz Dual Intel MacPro. Tried the disk utility and still it's not showing. Checked the Finder Menu-Preferences and the settings are fine. What to try next..anyone...?

Comment: Do you use virtualization software on your Mac, like VMware Fusion? If a VM is running and the USB drive is connected to it the drive won't show up in the Finder nor in Disk Utility. Otherwise, I'd say the flash drive is broken (or your Mac's USB port). Even if the drive wasn't unplugged properly it should definitely be listed in Disk Utility. Have you tried plugging it in another computer?

Comment: Thanx for responding..I don't use virtualization and I even tried on a different computer a Mac and a PC but still nothing. Guess it's really broken :(

Comment: Open Applications>Utilties>Terminal, type `sudo tail -f /var/log/system.log` (type your password if asked), hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a couple of times and then plug your flash drive. If you see timeout messages similar to this: ` AppleUSBEHCI[0xXXXXXXXX] ::Found a transaction past the completion deadline on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 6, EP: 2)` or this: `USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous) timeout`, or if you don't see USB messages at all, the drive is probably damaged beyond remedy.